# Inner Class in Java creates reference to self as attribute

Tags: java, inner-classes

I have a simple class in my Java program that models a BST of generic types. In this class there is an inner class that models the nodes of the BST.

```
public class Tree<T extends Comparable<T>> {
  private class TreeElement {
    private T element;
    private TreeElement left = null;
    private TreeElement right = null;

    public TreeElement(T element){
      this.element=element;
    }
  }

  public TreeElement root=null;
  public void insert(T element) {
    if (root==null){
      root=new TreeElement(element);
      return;
    }
   //More Code here that is not relevant
  }
}

Tree tree = new Tree();
tree.insert(5);
```

After inserting an Integer-Element into my Tree, I get the following Tree object (from debugger):

```
tree = {Tree@1147} 
 root = {Tree$TreeElement@1157} 
  element = {Integer@1155} 5
  left = null
  right = null
  this$0 = {Tree@1147} 
   root = {Tree$TreeElement@1157} 
    element = {Integer@1155} 5
    left = null
    right = null
    this$0 = {Tree@1147}
```

This would go on for as long as I keep clicking, so its an recursive reference to itself.

My questions are:

- Where does the this$0-reference to itself come from?
- How do I avoid it?

From my understanding, my Tree Object should only have a root Object that has 3 Attributes (element, left, right).

Comment: Make inner class `static`.

Comment: This doesn't work. When trying to reference my private T element in the inner class, I get the Error "tree.this cannot be referenced from static context"

Comment: Well, if you need a reference to the outer class in the inner class, then you can't avoid having a reference to the outer class in the inner class. :)

Comment: The general program structure is ,sadly, given by the assignment (This is part of a university assignment). So this is not how I would do it, but rather how it has to be implemented. As just changing the inner class to static doesnt work, any other approaches?

Comment: Approaches to what? What is the problem you think you need to solve? In what way does it prevent your code from working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where does the `this$0-reference` to itself come from?

It comes from the class being non-static.

> How do I avoid it?

This reference is what enables your code to reference `tree.this`. You cannot get rid of it, unless you are willing to supply `tree.this` to the method that uses it through some alternative way (e.g. by passing it as a parameter all the time).

Once you figure out how to not reference `tree.this` from your code, making `TreeElement` class `static` would get rid of the hidden reference to `Tree`.

Comment: When I declare my TreeElement Class static I get  the Error "tree.this cannot be referenced from static context". How to avoid this then? Sorry, nested classes are new for me and make no sense to me

Comment: @chubbseN Figure out how to not reference it if you can: in each place where compiler reports an unsatisfied reference of `tree.this` figure out if you need the reference there, and if yes, how are you going to pass it there without storing it on `TreeElement`. This is not something you can do without seeing the offending code.

Comment: @chubbseN You'll have to parameterize your TreeElement if you want it to be static. Right  now it is referencing the parameter of the outer class. (I think I have not tested this) Edit: sorry, you must be using tree.this elsewhere. I didn't realize.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a 'recursive reference to self'. It's a non-recursive reference to the instance of the outer class via which the inner-class object was created. You can get rid of it by changing the inner class to static, but this will cause other code problems if you access members of the outer class from within it. Such as `tree.this`.

This is not a problem, so you don't need to solve it.